# Splitting a Camel String and appending the word to a list

Tags: python, string, list

I have managed to append the first UpperCase letter of each of the CamelCase word in the string to the list , however, need help in appending  the small letters between the Capital letters ..need this to be done in a simple way without using any SPLIT functions.

```
array=list()
string="ThisIsCamelCase"

for i in string:
    if i.isupper():
    array.append(i)

print (array)
```

EDITED:
I'm looking for something like:

```
array=list()
string="ThisIsCamelCase"
upper="z"
lower="y"
for i in string:
    if i.isupper():  # upper case
        upper=i
        array.append(upper)
    elif i[1:].islower():
        lower=i
        array.append(lower)
print (array)
```

Comment: Looks like you just copied your homework here. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I want to extract the small letters between the upper case letters

Answer (score 0):

In case of lower-case letter, append to the last word (`array[-1]`):

```
words = []
string = "ThisIsCamelCase"

for i in string:
    if i.isupper() or not words:  # upper case / very first letter
        words.append(i)
    else:                         # lower case
        words[-1] += i

print(words) # => ['This', 'Is', 'Camel', 'Case']
```

Comment: great thank you. Can you explain this line: array[-1] += iwhat is the +=

Comment: `words[-1]` -> last word ;  `words[-1] += i` is equivalent to `words[-1] = words[-1] + i` meaning append the lower case letter to the last word.

Comment: Not sure I understand this...Is there a simpler way to understand the extraction of small letters from the string and appending them to the capital letters already appended to the list

Comment: @PythonHelp, Please read the tutorial about `if.. else..` statement: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements